# FLAT_INTERFACE in local.conf in devstack

Tags: openstack, devstack

I have two questions regarding devstack.

For the All-In-One Single Machine setup for devstack, there is a setting FLAT_INTERFACE=eth0. Where is this variable FLAT_INTERFACE used in the stack.sh script? I can see the variable FIXED_RANGE is used in stack.sh.

I have a Ubuntu on the company network with DHCP. I installed devstack on this Ubuntu. I want the VMs on this Ubuntu to get the same subnet ip address as the ubuntu PC from the company DHCP. How do I do that? It seems the All-In-One Single Machine setup requires the FIXED_RANGE to be configured and the VMs will get ip address from the FIXED_RANGE, which is not the same as the subnet on the company DHCP.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/configuration.html#local-conf at Minimal configuration section, it would guide you about a sample config of you devstack installation.

Mainly it says the following:

Minimal Configuration

While stack.sh is happy to run without a localrc section in local.conf, devlife is better when there are a few minimal variables set. This is an example of a minimal configuration that touches the values that most often need to be set.
[...]

```
[[local|localrc]]
ADMIN_PASSWORD=secrete
DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_TOKEN=a682f596-76f3-11e3-b3b2-e716f9080d50
#FIXED_RANGE=172.31.1.0/24
#FLOATING_RANGE=192.168.20.0/25
#HOST_IP=10.3.4.5
```

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.